# Selenium.find_element_by_id error

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying autofill some data into a website. I downloaded selenium and it seems to have no problem with importing. However when I look for the id "value" an error occurs.

> File "C:\Users\Thomas\My Documents\LiClipse Workspace\BurgerBoiPlz\src\root\nested__init__.py", line 14, in 
>       username = selenium.find_element_by_id("value")
>   NameError: name 'selenium' is not defined
>   Exception ignored in: >
>   Traceback (most recent call last):

What am I doing wrong?

code:

```
import urllib
import lib2to3
import requests
import sys

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

chromedriver = r'C:\Users\Thomas\Documents\LiClipse Workspace\BurgerBoiPlz\src\root\nested\chromedriver.exe'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
browser.get('https://temp-mail.org/en/option/change')

username = selenium.find_element_by_id("value")
username.send_keys("YourUsername")
```

Comment: You want to use `browser.find_element_by_id` and not `selenium.find_element_by_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Any operation you need to perform on the UI requires the driver instance that is been created .

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
browser.get('https://temp-mail.org/en/option/change')

username = selenium.find_element_by_id("value")
username.send_keys("YourUsername")
```

In your code the driver instance you created is in the first line **browser**
So, any UI operation you need to perform will be done using  this instance .
like you did it in the first line

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
```

Likewise, you need to find any element on this driver instance you will have to write

```
 username = browser.find_element_by_id("value")
```

Comment: Thank you @tester. I still have an error with the code. This is my input
chromedriver = r'C:\Users\Thomas\Documents\LiClipse Workspace\BurgerBoiPlz\src\root\nested\chromedriver.exe'

browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
browser.get('https://temp-mail.org/en/option/change')


username = browser.find_element_by_id("value")

and I get this error 
elenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"value"}
="mail" type="text" class="form-control" id="mail" value="">

Comment: @CubedManiac If you have noticed you previous exception **name 'selenium' is not defined Exception ignored in: > Traceback (most recent call last):** has been resolved. The new exception you are getting is **NoSuchElementException** that is a selenium  exception which occurs basically when you are unable to locate the element on UI. Please try to check the locator you are using.